Android Emulator GPS Location Not Working
I've been unable to get GPS location emulation working on any of the Android emulators.
I've tried multiple Android emulators and APIs but haven't managed to get the GPS emulation to work. When clicking on the "Location" settings for an emulator, I just get the following screen:

The emulators' location has been enabled:


I've tried the following emulators:

Pixel 8 Pro
Pixel 8 with custom hardware profile
Pixel 7
Pixel 6
Pixel 5

I've tried the following Android APIs:

VanillaIceCream (x86_64)
API 35 (x86_64)
UpsideDownCake (x86_64)
Tiramisu (x86_64)

Has anyone else experienced this issue or know of a possible fix?
Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-241.18034.62.2411.12071903, built on July 10, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.11+0--11852314 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4068M
Cores: 16
Registry:
  ide.experimental.ui=true


Did you follow the instructions in the documentation for using the Location extended controls? Your screenshot suggests that you did not search for or set a location.

I've tried searching for "Single points" and "Routes", but the search doesn't work. It's supposed to look like this, but it's not loading the map at all.
